# Prisma 1-1 optional relation

Tags: database, postgresql, prisma

I'm trying to create optional (1-1) relation between Cart and User models.

My prisma schema

```
generator client {
    provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
    provider = "postgresql"
    url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
    id        Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
    name      String?
    email     String    @unique
    password  String
    role      UserRole  @default(USER)
    createdAt DateTime  @default(now())
    updatedAt DateTime  @default(now()) @updatedAt
    Session   Session[]
    Product   Product[]
    Cart      Cart?     @relation(fields: [cartId], references: [id])
    cartId    String? @unique
}

model Cart {
    id               String          @id @default(cuid())
    cartProducts     CartToProduct[]
    createdAt        DateTime        @default(now())
    updatedAt        DateTime        @default(now()) @updatedAt
    deliveryMethod   DeliveryMethod? @relation(fields: [deliveryMethodId], references: [id])
    deliveryMethodId Int?            @default(1)
    packStationId    String?
    User             User?
}
```

In my case i would like to create cart for guest user, but when user will login to application i would like assign cart to logged user, but im getting error when i tryin to run `prisma migrate dev && prisma generate`

Following error ->

A unique constraint covering the columns `[cartId]` on the table `User` will be added. If there are existing duplicate values, this will fail.

Error: Prisma Migrate has detected that the environment is non-interactive, which is not supported.

Comment: You should not add unique constraint to a nullable column, this may cause only one NULL value in the entire table and prisma already warn you about this.

Answer (score 0):

Look like you're running command in an non-interactive enviroment, check out this documentation

https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-migrate/prisma-migrate-limitations-issues#prisma-migrate-in-non-interactive-environments